# Manage a collection of settings in memory with global scope

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, mvvm

I have a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) app and a bunch of read/write settings that need to be accessible from various view models. a setting can be any type (`string`, `bool`, etc) and all are settable, but only from a 'Settings' view. I also need the view models to be notified when any setting has been updated and which one that was.

Here is an `enum` with all the settings:

```
public enum Setting
{
    SettingA,
    SettingB,
    //etc 
}
```

here is the settings class, as a singleton:

```
  internal sealed class Settings
{
    private static volatile Settings _instance;
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();
    private Dictionary<Setting, object> _settings;

    private Settings()
    {
        _settings = new Dictionary<Setting, object>();
        _settings.Add(Setting.SettingA, 1000);
        _settings.Add(Setting.SettingB, 1000);    
    }

    public static Settings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new Settings();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateSetting(Setting key, object value)
    {
        if (_settings[key] != value)
        {
            _settings[key] = value;
            TriggerNotification(key, value);
        }
    }

    public T GetSetting<T>(Setting key)
    {
        return (T)_settings[key];
    }

    public event EventHandler<SettingsUpdatedEventArgs> OnSettingsUpdated;

    private void TriggerNotification(Setting key, object value)
    {
        var handler = OnSettingsUpdated;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new SettingsUpdatedEventArgs(key, value));
        }
    }
}
```

here is the overrided event args:

```
 public class SettingsUpdatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Setting Type { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public SettingsUpdatedEventArgs(Setting type, object value)
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

and here is how it is used:

```
    //update a setting value
    Settings.Instance.UpdateSetting(Setting.SettingA,200);


    //retrieve a setting value
    var value = Settings.Instance.GetSetting<int>(Setting.SettingA);

    //register a listener
    Settings.Instance.OnSettingsUpdated += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Type == Setting.SettingA)
        {
            var result = args.Value;
        }

    };
```

and now my questions:

- Is there a problem having the settings class as a singleton?
- Is this a type-safe way to get the setting values?
- Is there a much better/simpler/more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to [codereview.se]! This is a very nice question. You maybe also want to check out our [chat] ;)

Comment: Very relevant to me right now. I've been struggling with a similar piece of code. Welcome to CR.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a type-safe way to get the setting values?

It's not type-safe in the sense that if you make a mistake in specifying the type parameter of `GetSetting`, or if someone sets  setting to the wrong type, you're going to get an exception.

I've struggled with this issue before and I have [created a solution to this that uses generic keys](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/12291/2041). It's by no means perfect, but you can use it as an inspiration.

Comment: awesome, I did something similar now! type safety done right :)